# How do I solve a problem in vgate geant 4?

Tags: geant4

I got vgate geat4 version 10.7.0. The installation is well. When I execute a mac, this error show me:

> COMAND NOT FOUND </gate/cylindrical PET/setMaterial Water>

I don´t know doing about this problem.